# htaccess rewrite rule, url doesn't work when i add a / at the end and it show error

Tags: .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^themobilesapp.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.themobilesapp.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ specification.php?url=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 404error.php


</IfModule>**strong text**
```

When I open the URL https://www.themobilesapp.com/Motorola-Moto-G4-Play-specifications-7443
it works fine but when i tried to open the URL by adding **"/"** in the last on the url like https://www.themobilesapp.com/Motorola-Moto-G4-Play-specifications-7443/

I have tried many but it doesn't solve my problem.
I want my URL as https://www.themobilesapp.com/Motorola-Moto-G4-Play-specifications-7443

Comment: I have added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1 [L,R=301]

it is redirecting to the url which doesn't have "/" in the end.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following Rules in your .htaccess file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes    
DirectorySlash Off

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^themobilesapp\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.themobilesapp.com/$1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ specification.php?url=$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 404error.php


</IfModule>
```

Also I saw in your previous edit that you need rule like rewriting to given php files with uri, you could cover all those rules with following single rule here:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([\w-]+)/?$  $1.php?url=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solved using the below code.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```